# What percentage of NPC missions are non-combat?

Tags: eve-online

I'm a pretty new player, and so far I've done the basic tutorial, the industry tutorial missions, and some of the exploration tutorial missions. Obviously I've focused on the non-combat side of the game, including skills.

However, when I went through several nearby systems, I wasn't able to find a single mission that didn't involve combat with pirates. I expected to find some 'build thing  X' or 'deliver thing Y', like in the tutorial missions.

Should I just start gearing up a combat ship, or are there lots of these crafting/delivery/etc missions out there and I'm just unlucky or looking in the wrong places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest patch has changed this significantly. There are now only three divisions:
 
Security - All combat missions.
Distribution - All courier missions.
Astrogeology - All mining missions.

Answer (score 10):

It depends on which NPCs you talk to. Some NPCs ("Command" NPCs) mostly give combat missions, some give mostly mining missions.

http://wiki.eveonline.com/wiki/Missions_Guide

That page has a table (Corporation Division vs. Mission Types) 
which contains the probabilities of each mission type based on NPC type.

If you don't want any combat missions, try "R&D" NPCs, they have 0% combat missions.

Comment: I tried going by agent job titles, but even folk with innocent-sounding titles (e.g. Administrator, accountant) wanted me to go blow something up. Is there a good way to search out the "right" NPCs?

Comment: @sjohnston The table on that page should provide a good guide.

Comment: Specifically, Accounting should be 91% courier, 9% kill. Administration is 23 % courier, 76% kill (and a little trade)

Comment: Ah, I did not see the link when I made the comment. *facepalm*

Comment: @sjohnston I may have added the link later :D

Comment: You can also check out departments with very low ratios of kill missions and simply reject those missions when you get them. You can reject something along the lines of 1 mission per 4 hours without a standing hit.